# How to understand a Scala's method declaration?

Tags: scala, methods

I'm new to Scala and got into troubles with understanding this declaration:

Here's the declaration from `Akka`'s `Props` object:

```
def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](): Props = __THE_DEFENITION_GOES_HERE__
```

Why can we use it like this:

```
val props = Props[TestActor]
```

where `class TestActor extends Actor`.  I'm curious about how just by `Generic Type` argument, the compiler is able to find the appropriate method defenition. How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some special magic involved with the `apply` method in a Scala `object`. This:

```
val something = Hello()
```

is special shortcut syntax for this:

```
val something = Hello.apply()
```

Similarly, looking at your example:

```
val props = Props[TestActor]
```

is just short syntax for this:

```
val props = Props.apply[TestActor]()
```

The `[TestActor]` is just filling in the type argument for the `apply` method.

Comment: But what does `ClassTag` mean in `T <: Actor: ClassTag`. It uses as `implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass`.

Comment: `ClassTag` is carries info about the class at runtime. The `:` defines a _context bound_ on `ClassTag`, which means "in the implicit scope there's an instance of ClassTag[T]"; it's syntactic sugar for `def apply[T <: Actor](implicit evidence: ClassTag[T])`.

For more information on the `ClassTag` class you can read this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

For specific info on context bounds there's this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html#what-is-a-context-bound

Comment: @user3663882 The `ClassTag` is a way to get around type erasure on the JVM.